# Swift: Button in UITableView cell gets triggered by Swipe-to-Delete

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uibutton, swift2

I know there is the same question for Objective-C and it has no answer, but maybe somebody has an idea.

I have an **UIButton** in a **UITableView** cell:

```
let tButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
tButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTap:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
cell.contentView.addSubview(tButton)
```

And my **commitEditingStyle** delegate looks this way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
}
```

When I start a swipe at the button, the buttons target gets fired.

[image: swipe2delTriggers]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ended up with:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    blocked = true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    blocked = false
}
```

And then determine uiStatus in the targets of my buttons like so:

```
func buttonTap(sender:UIButton!){

    if blocked == false {

        ...do something

    }
}
```

Not very elegant, but it works. Good Night